# Public rules for real time database firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What is the problem with enabling all users to read and write to the real time database?

Lets say i have a button that saves data in the database, like what is today's date, what's the problem to lets other users to use this button and save for me today's date in database?
There is another way to change database data besides clicking the button?

What i want to do is to able other users of the app to do some work for me by clicking buttons that do "background work (update database)" so when i open the app the data is already updated.

Thanks.

Comment: As long as you aren't depending on the value of the database information to do additional computations, there's nothing wrong with public access. However, think about usernames/passwords - you wouldn't want everybody changing that

Comment: And, yes, there are other ways to update database without clicking the button. Such as starting an infinite loop to repeatedly do the update

Comment: If i do additional computations based on the value, what is the problem if the only way to change the value is to click the button and when a user clicks the button, my updateDatabase method is called so he can't damage or ruin/destroy my database, he just clicks the button, he doesn't have a full control about what to write to the database right? how the user can do this?

Comment: "There is another way to change database data besides clicking the button?" Yes. There is no way to limit access to your Firebase Database to just your app. That why you use Firebase's security rules to restrict **what can be done** to your database and **by which user**. That way is doesn't matter whether they use your app or find another way to access/change the data. As long as they adhere to your rules, the result is the same.

Comment: It's hard to give an accurate answer, but if your button isn't reading data from an input field, for example, and always inserting the same data (like the current time the button is pressed), then it sounds like no damage could be done

Comment: Frank van Puffelen - how can a user get access to the database besides my app? is there a source to read about that?  cricket_007 - my button isn't reading data from an input field, it does an "background service" with jsoup and the website i use is constant, so the user don't have control of this when clicking the button, clicking the button only "starts the service for the background work" if its not already been done by another user earlier.

Comment: answering your question to @FrankvanPuffelen, someone can easily deobfuscate or pull up all strings from your app's APK file to get the Firebase API key and the database URL. Once they got that information, they can easily create a javascript file to alter the database, to remove all data `ref.setValue(null);` or get all data `ref.on('value', function);`